# Elasticsearch 2.4 - Combining Date Range Filter with Date Histogram

Tags: elasticsearch

I have query :

```
{
  "size": 0,
 "aggs": {
   "data_bulanan" : {
    "date_histogram" : {
        "field" : "creation_date",
        "interval" : "month",
        "format": "MMMM"
        },
        "aggs": {
          "SvcCharge" : {
              "sum": {
              "field": "service_tax"
              }
          },
          "GvtTax" : {
              "sum": {
              "field": "government_tax"
              }
          },
          "Discount" : {
             "sum" : {
             "field": "discount"
              }
          }

        }
    }
  }
}
```

And i want to add the date range from date to date . for example from 2014-01-01 to 2015-01-01 .

How to add it?

thank you

Comment: So you would basically like to limit the result set to these dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to limit the resultset to the specified dates above, you need to combine a query to your aggregation, you can do it like so

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
      "bool": {
          "filter": {
              "range": {
                  "creation_date": {
                      "gte": "2014-01-01",
                      "lte": "2015-01-01"
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "data_bulanan": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "creation_date",
        "interval": "month",
        "format": "MMMM"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "SvcCharge": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "service_tax"
          }
        },
        "GvtTax": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "government_tax"
          }
        },
        "Discount": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "discount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how to apply filter for example , i want result only for "user_id" : 1 . 

in mysql we have "where user_id = 1"